# Para que serve o operador ">" em CSS?

Tags: css

Em alguns [css](/questions/tagged/css) vejo o operador "**>**" :

```css
#panel_conteiner > p {
  color:red;
}

#panel_conteiner div{
  padding:5px;
  margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel_conteiner">
  <p>
    teste teste
  </p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      Legend
    </legend>
    <div>
      <p>
        conteudo
      </p>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Qual sua Utilidade?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean

Comment: Muito boa pergunta +1. Acho melhor ter essa pergunta em português

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para pegar o elemento filho imediato, e não qualquer um filho.

Por exemplo:

```css
.avo
{
    background-color:red;
    height:50px;
}
.avo > .pai > .filho {
   color:red;
   background-color:yellow;
   height:20px;
 }

.avo .filho{
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="avo">
  <div class="pai">
     <div class="filho">Eu sou o filho</div>
  </div>
  <div class="filho">Eu sou o filho</div>
</div>
```

Isso é muito útil em casos de menus onde você não quer que uma definição, mesma feita diretamente em tags, não sejam aplicadas para todos os elementos.

Exemplo:

```
nav.menu > ul{}
nav.menu > ul > li {}
```

Se eu tiver que colocar um outro `ul` pra criar um submenu dentro da li da classe `.menu`, não interferirá, já que o css está definido para o filho imediato de `nav.menu` (`nav.menu > ul`) e não para qualquer `ul`dentro de `nav.menu` (`nav.menu ul`).

Então resumindo a diferença entre as duas formas poderia ser colocada assim:

`nav.menu > ul` = Filho imediato
   `nav.menu ul`   = Qualquer filho

Answer (score 3):

O operador `>` serve para indicar filhos diretos. Veja:

```css
#panel_container > p{
    font-size: 28pt;  
}
```

```html
<div id="panel_container">
    <p>Oi</p>
    <div class="teste">
        <p>Oi</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Perceba que somente o primeiro "Oi" ficou com `28pt` de tamanho de fonte. Experimente retirar o operador `>` para você ver o que acontece! (Spoiler: nesse caso, qualquer `p` que seja filho de `#panel_container`, independente da profundidade, vai receber a propriedade).